# Visual Studio Online/VSTS Test Categories

Tags: tfs, nunit, azure-devops, specflow

[image]

Can anyone advise how you can show the test category where "unspecified" is shown in the screenshot as that I can group test result output by category/tag.

I would like to be able to do this from both nunit and specflow tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some groups that can group tests, but aren’t existing in nunit and specflow tests, so you can’t group test with them (the result is Unspecified), you can group by Container, test run.

[image]

A related user voice that you can vote: [VSTS Group Test Results by Namespace/Class](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/15801964-vsts-group-test-results-by-namespace-class), you also can submit a new user voice.

Answer (score 0):

As @starain-MSFT wrote, it depends how you group your tests.
There is an option to group by Category and if the test case has no Category set, it is in the group Unspecified.

In NUnit you use the Category- Attribute (https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Category-Attribute) which is then used from the NUnit VS Adapter to inform the test explorer (VSTest) about this.

For SpecFlow:
To get this category attribute generated on the test methods in the code-behind file, you have to use tags (see https://cucumber.io/docs/reference#gherkin in section "Tags")